# Не сортируются позиции в массиве

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Есть массив `[#<ProductAttributeValue position: 5>,#<ProductAttributeValue position: 2>,#<ProductAttributeValue position: 4>,#<ProductAttributeValue position: 1>,#<ProductAttributeValue position: 3>]`

`ProductAttribute` has_many `ProductAttributeValue`

Сделал кнопку, которая сортирует `ProductAttributeValue` по атрибуту `position`.

```
def sort_attributes
    ProductAttribute.all.map do |pa|
      a = ProductAttributeValue.where(product_attribute_id: pa.id).sort_by(&:position)
    end

    redirect_to product_attributes_path
end
```

Нажимаю кнопку, Код ничего не делает и в логах только

```
  ProductAttributeValue Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "product_attribute_values".* FROM "product_attribute_values" WHERE "product_attribute_values"."product_attribute_id" = 1878
  ProductAttributeValue Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "product_attribute_values".* FROM "product_attribute_values" WHERE "product_attribute_values"."product_attribute_id" = 1771
  ProductAttributeValue Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "product_attribute_values".* FROM "product_attribute_values" WHERE "product_attribute_values"."product_attribute_id" = 2241
  ProductAttributeValue Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "product_attribute_values".* FROM "product_attribute_values" WHERE "product_attribute_values"."product_attribute_id" = 2242
  ProductAttributeValue Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "product_attribute_values".* FROM "product_attribute_values" WHERE "product_attribute_values"."product_attribute_id" = 2197
```

Хотя когда дебажжу, то вроде бы позиции меняются. т.е. получается массив с `[#<ProductAttributeValue position: 1>,#<ProductAttributeValue position: 2>,#<ProductAttributeValue position: 3>,#<ProductAttributeValue position: 4>,#<ProductAttributeValue position: 5>]`

Запрос должен быть примерно таким, но эквивалент в ruby не могу составить:

```
  ProductAttributeValue Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "product_attribute_values".* FROM "product_attribute_values" WHERE "product_attribute_values"."product_attribute_id" = 1651 ORDER BY "product_attribute_values"."position"
  SQL (44.9ms)  UPDATE "product_attribute_values" SET "position" = 0 WHERE "product_attribute_values"."id" = 7537
  SQL (9.2ms)  UPDATE "product_attribute_values" SET "position" = 1 WHERE "product_attribute_values"."id" = 7474
  SQL (9.3ms)  UPDATE "product_attribute_values" SET "position" = 2 WHERE "product_attribute_values"."id" = 7395
  SQL (9.1ms)  UPDATE "product_attribute_values" SET "position" = 3 WHERE "product_attribute_values"."id" = 7216
  SQL (9.5ms)  UPDATE "product_attribute_values" SET "position" = 4 WHERE "product_attribute_values"."id" = 7046
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что `sort_by` добавляет `ORDER BY` в SQL? У него в документации так написано? =) Ознакомьтесь с [основами ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сортировки записей ActiveRecord можно использовать метод [order](http://rusrails.ru/active-record-query-interface#ordering)

```
@sorted_values = ProductAttribute.first.product_attribute_values.order("product_attribute_values.position")
```

Далее результат выполнения запроса @sorted_values можно использовать в представлении.

Однако, в Вашем случае, выполнение метода *redirect_to* в конце приведенного примера выполнят переход на другой экшн, в котором, грубо говоря, результаты данной сортировки уже учитываться не будут...